# C# Speech Recognition Store Words

Tags: c#

I am currently using

```
if (e.Result.Text == prefix + "who is bill gates") { System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Gates"); }
```

I need to figure out how I can just make it

```
if (e.Result.Text == prefix + "who is" + GET WhoIs) { System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + WhoIs); }
```

I need it to work dynamically if possible. I have no idea how I can do this any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What big is your project?

If you know that the words in the start of the sentence will be the same, just take them from your string and then use the rest as the text.

If you want to work with something more dynamic and your time and budget is limited, checkout [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/)

Else, you need to read about NLP. How to tag words, determine Noun, verb, etc